# select multiple line breaks regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So what I am trying to do is replace one or more instances of newline with the br tag in javascript.  So far I have:

```
description.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

However if there is a case where there are 2/3 newlines's in a row I get 2/3 br tags.  Is there a way in regex to say give me any instances of one or more newlines's in a row and replace that whole thing with one br tag so that even if I have:

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
```

that would get replace with just:

```
<br >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `+` quantifier to indicate one or more matches.

```
description.replace(/\n+/g, '<br />');
```

PS: you need to read more about regular expressions, this was fairly straight forward.

Comment: I swear that I tried that and that is was not working for me but now it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
description.replace(/\n+/g, '<br />');
```

happy homework

Comment: Sorry - It looked that way - When you have been been changing code around and know it should work on each change you make and it still refuses to work even when reduced to the simplest it is easier to type it into stack overflow than bash your head against the wall.